# Retrieve Database Value Into ASP.NET a Databound Dropdownlist without Duplicate Values

Tags: c#, asp.net

Whenever the user clicks the Update Profile button, he will be led to the page where in, all the information he saved during his registration will be displayed in textboxes and dropdownlist UPON PAGE LOAD. (Dropdownlists are databound)

Using the code below, I was able to do it, **However when I change values in DDLDepartment (first dropdownlist), the DDLGroup (Second dropdownlist) autpostback and duplicate the values.**

*DDLDepartment and DDLGroup are interrelated because DDLGroup is filtered depending on the value selected in DDLDepartment*

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) // important
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader myReader = null;


            string cmdstr = "SELECT * from USERSONLINE where Username = '" + Session["Username"] + "'";
            SqlCommand userExist = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);

            myReader = userExist.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                txtEmpID.Text = (myReader["EmpId"].ToString());
                txtFirstName.Text = (myReader["FirstName"].ToString());
                txtLastName.Text = (myReader["LastName"].ToString());
                txtUsername.Text = (myReader["Username"].ToString());
                ddlDepartment.SelectedItem.Text = (myReader["Department"].ToString());
                ddlGroup.SelectedItem.Text = (myReader["GroupName"].ToString());

            }
            con.Close();
        }   
    }
```

html mark-up

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" AutoPostBack="True"  runat="server"  AppendDataBoundItems="True"  BackColor="#F3F3F3" ForeColor="#838383" 
             Height="25px" style="text-align: left"  Width="135px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDepartment" DataTextField="DepartmentName" DataValueField="DepartmentID" OnDataBound="ddlDepartment_DataBound"  >
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select Department</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>



<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGroup" runat="server" BackColor="#F3F3F3"  ForeColor="#838383" Height="25px" style="text-align: left; margin-bottom: 0px;" Width="145px" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceGroup" DataTextField="GroupName" DataValueField="GroupID" AutoPostBack="true" OnDataBound="ddlGroup_DataBound" AppendDataBoundItems="true" > 
              <asp:ListItem>Select Group</asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: Use events, especially the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of `ddlDepartment`. Also, why do you need `AppendDataBoundItems=true`. This makes only sense if you want to add a "non-selected"-item manually.

Comment: Yes, I am inserting a non-selected item, like "Select Group" that's why I use that attribute and set it to true

Answer (score 0):

When selecting Department and Group use the following

```
ddlDepartment.Items.FindByValue((myReader["Department"].ToString())).Selected = true;
ddlGroup.Items.FindByValue((myReader["GroupName"].ToString())).Selected = true;
```

Comment: In the SelectedIndexChanged event